# Issue with PDF file using getContentAsPDF

Tags: apex, pdf, getcontentaspdf, blob.topdf, paypal

I am creating attachment with paypal invoice using getContent method in apex and attaching file under record but there issue with pdf file. it's not creating properly

Here is my code :

```
String paypalInvUrl = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/invoice/s/pdf/pay/INV2-2K8L-4RAQ-JBXG-CEA2?skipAuth=true&isDownload=true';
 PageReference pg = new PageReference(paypalInvUrl);
Blob b;
 b = pg.getContentAsPDF();

Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = '0061D00000Gcr0b', Name = 'pdfAttachmentDemo5.pdf', body = b); 
        insert attach;
```

using getContentAsPDF getting this error in pdf file.[image]

Usinf getContent in code getting this error.
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity -- why not to make regular callout to it and get binary data via getBodyAsBlob() and then save it as attachment?

Comment: Thanks @kurunve for the answer, it works.